# Call QMF procedure from .NET

Tags: db2, mainframe, zos

We're doing Windows development against a DB2 database with QMF v9.1. We hard-code many of our SQL queries directly into our applications, even though they are already stored in QMF.

However, I was told that a built-in stored procedure exists that is able to return results from a QMF query or procedure. But the person could not tell me the name of the stored procedure.

Would anyone be able to share their experience in regards to the above? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`Q.DSQQMFSP`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.qmf10.doc.iandm/storedprocexamples.htm). The QMF Stored Proc interface has to be [enabled](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.qmf10.doc.iandm/installstoredproc.htm), so it's not a "default" option.

Once that's done, it should be like calling [any other stored proc](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/t0011824.html) from .NET